# Запись в контейнер list (STL)

Tags: c++, stl, std-list

Есть файл input.txt со следующим содержимым:

> Ivan Petrov Ivan

Я записаю данные в контейнер **list**:

```
string str;
list <string> list1;
ifstream input("input.txt");
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    input >> str;
    list1.push_back(str);
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы не записывались повторы - чтобы запись *Ivanov* не повторилась?

Comment: Вообще непонятно зачем в данной ситуации использовать std::list

Comment: Мне в дальнейшем надо сортировать список по алфавиту.

Comment: @derkode std::set автоматически сортирует элементы при помощи компаратора который передаётся как второй аргумент шаблона (по умолчанию это std::less<T> то есть std::less<std::string>)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте std::set

Comment: или std::map, если нужно хранить именно пару: ключ-значение.

Answer (score 0):

Предварительно проверять, содержит ли list такое значение. Можно использовать алгоритм find для этого. find возвращает итератор на конец списка, если не нашел указанное значение.

```
#include <algorithm>
...
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
   input >> str;
   if(std::find(list1.begin(), list1.end(), str) == list1.end())
       list1.push_back(str);
}
```